# python sum values in columns taken from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have a dataframe ("MUNg") like this:

```
MUN_id    Col1
1-2       a
3         b
4-5-6     c
...
```

And another dataframe ("ppc") like this:

```
     id     population
0     1     20
1     2     25
2     3     4
3     4     45
4     5     100
5     6     50
...
```

I need to create a column in "MUNg" that contains the total population obtained by summing the population corresponding to the ids from "pcc", that are present in MUN_id

Expected result:

```
MUN_id    Col1    total_population
1-2       a       45
3         b       4
4-5-6     c       195
...
```

I don't write how I tried to achieve this, because I am new to python and I don't know how to do it.

```
MUNg['total_population']=?
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `split` and `explode` your string into new rows, `map` the population data and `GroupBy.agg` to get the sum:

```
MUNg['total_population'] = (MUNg['MUN_id']
 .str.split('-')
 .explode()
 .astype(int) # required if "id" in "ppc" is an integer, comment if string
 .map(ppc.set_index('id')['population'])
 .groupby(level=0).sum()
)
```

output:

```
  MUN_id Col1  total_population
0    1-2    a                45
1      3    b                 4
2  4-5-6    c               195
```